# Buy 3 of a subset of products get x% discount

Tags: promotions, enterprise-1.10, shopping-cart-price-rules

We are trying to set up a promotion where if you buy 3 of a subset of products you get x% discount.  It looked like we should be able to do this out of the box using sales rules conditions but I can;t get it to work.

Basically, I have set the rule conditions to be:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

If total quantity  equals or greater than  3  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
    SKU  is one of  sku1,sku2,sku3
```

And the action to be:

```
Percent of product price discount 10%
```

When I add 3 of a the qualifying products (i.e. 1 of sku1 and 2 of sku2) I would expect to get a 10% discount but I'm still being charged full price.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  This has been tested on our dev site and a clean Magento install with sample data.

Comment: Could you please submit a screenshot of your setting? As in current 1.13.0.2 I wasn't able to set a condition by SKU.

Comment: Here are my conditions: [link](http://i39.tinypic.com/2wr3o15.jpg) and my actions are here: [link](http://i40.tinypic.com/1znyc2f.png)

Comment: @RichardCleverley : is it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, have figured this out.  Seems to be a problem with configurable products.  Basically I was setting the condition to only look at the child product of a configurable.  If I also include the actual configurable SKU in the conditions then it works fine.

NOTE: you also need to enter the SKUs in the action conditions otherwise the discount will apply to your whole basket and not just the products you want to offer the discount on.